# Symfony2 sending form data to the database. Nothing happens

Tags: php, symfony

It looks like a simple task. I am doing this by using the documentation, however I am just not creating a new user. I dont get any errors, but I dont get the user too. I create my form in a seperate class like this:

```
class RegisterFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

                $builder                

                ->add('firstname', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'First Name * ',
                'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'First Name')))
                ->add('email', 'email', array(
                'label' => 'Email * ',
                'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Email')))
                ->add('password', 'password', array(
                'label' => 'Password * ',
                'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Password')))

                ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Register'));



    }

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Mp\ShopBundle\Entity\Users',
    ));
}

public function getName()
    {
        return 'register_form_users';
    }
}
```

In my second controller I get the database, create a new user and add the information to that user? At least I think I am... What is wrong here?

```
public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {   
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $products = $em->getRepository('MpShopBundle:Product')->findAll();

            $user = new Users();

            $form = $this->createForm(new RegisterFormType(), $user);


            if ($form->isValid()) {

                $firstname = $form->get('firstname')->getData();
                $user->setFirstname($firstname);
                $email = $form->get('email')->getData();
                $user->setEmail($email);
                $password = $form->get('password')->getData();
                $user->setPassword($password);

                $em->persist($user);
                $em->flush();

            }

                return $this->render('MpShopBundle:Frontend:registration.html.twig',  array(
               'products'=>$products,
               'form'=>$form->createView(),    
               ));  
    }
```

Comment: If nothing happens, then your form probably isn't valid.

Comment: But I get the post 200 request successfully

Comment: It is because you don't send any other HTTP status code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony2 nothing happens when I display my form inside a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30261422/symfony2-nothing-happens-when-i-display-my-form-inside-a-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function registerAction(Request $request)
{   
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $products = $em->getRepository('MpShopBundle:Product')->findAll();

        $user = new Users();

        $form = $this->createForm(new RegisterFormType(), $user);

        /** add this code */
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        /** add this code */


        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $firstname = $form->get('firstname')->getData();
            $user->setFirstname($firstname);
            $email = $form->get('email')->getData();
            $user->setEmail($email);
            $password = $form->get('password')->getData();
            $user->setPassword($password);

            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();

        }

            return $this->render('MpShopBundle:Frontend:registration.html.twig',  array(
           'products'=>$products,
           'form'=>$form->createView(),    
           ));  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `$form->handleRequest($request)` before `$form->isValid()` and it should work. Because you're creating a form but not proccessing the data from request. You can look at the [source](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.6/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/HttpFoundation/HttpFoundationRequestHandler.php#L45) if you want.